# Systemd stuck looping through sssd daemon

Tags: systemd, raspberrypi, 20.10, sssd

I recently applied [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290803/ubuntu-20-10-system-security-services-daemon-failed-to-start/1318844#1318844) fix to my fairly recent install of Ubuntu 20.4 on my Raspberry PI 4 in an attempt to correct [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1900642) sssd bug.

I ran the following commands:

sudo cp /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/sssd/conf/sssd.conf /etc/sssd/

sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

Then I rebooted.

Now systemd is stuck on an infinite loop with the following set of messages getting printed out infinitely:

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
[  OK  ] Stopped System Security Services Daemon.
Starting System Security Services Daemon...
[FAILED] Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
See 'systemctl status sssd.service' for details.
```

I'm a total Linux n00b, so please forgive me if I did something incredibly stupid here. I'm afraid i've bricked my install of Ubuntu...unless one of you kind people can tell me how to escape this tragic fate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that description I would think you did not bother to copy the old file to a backup first. Actually now I read the descriptions you fix problem that is not a problem only an annoyance. And it is for the next operating system version not the version you run. The good news is the file is unimportant to the boot process if it is a proper file it will boot with it if not like the improper file you put in place it will make the boot fail. Solution is to  mount the sd card on another machine and delete the file.

Comment: Okay I loaded it up into Raspbian and deleted the sssd.conf file like you said and now I can log in no problem.

I think i'm jus gonna disable sssd as my fix for now since I really don't need the service.

@HappyTux, I can't thank you enough for your help! If you're ever in the SF Bay Area, let me know. I'll buy you a beer.